# Express: How to pass request to specific handler?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In my Express app I have an `all('/', ...)` on the root path. Here I check a failure flag and want to either pass on the request to the `next` handler or if something went wrong, like the DB connection couldn't be made, or I want to pass the request directly to the `/error` route but I don't want to redirect.

Can express hand the request directly to `/error` or do I have to explicitly call the handler for that route?

```
app = express()
var errors = ...

app.all('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if(errors) {
    // route to /error
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

app.get('/error', (req, res, next) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the handler for your error route separately and call it directly instead of calling next, but what you really want is to [define error handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). Something like:

```
app.all('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if(errors) {
    next(errors)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
app.use((err, req, res, next) => { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I'm looking for!